# Tips for tracking down valgrind memory leaks

Tags: c, valgrind

Any tips for tracking stuff down? Techniques? Any tools useful to check callers of function x(some parts of the call stack appear as ??? or are skipped).

Does --track-origins=yes make things much slower(the program I'm using it on seems to time out when I try to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with optimizations (e.g. -O3) can cause some functions to be optimized out, and could result in the ???'s you're seeing.